# Colour coding two tables based on multiplication results

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

i'm trying to colour code two tables. samples are blow

| table1 | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e | a*e | b*e | c*e |
| f | a*f | b*f | c*f |
| g | a*g | b*g | c*g |

and

| table2 | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E | A*E | B*E | C*E |
| F | A*F | B*F | C*F |
| G | A*G | B*G | C*G |

I want to color match the cells from both tables where cell value from table 1 range (2:,2:) multiplied by cell value from table2 range (2:,2:) lies between two number X and Y (not related to table)

this question is for excel Version 2305

what i tried so far

`=AND(A1*D1>=($G$1-$G$2), A1*D1<=($G$1+$G$2))` 
as conditional formating where G1 and G2 are numbers for X and Y and A1 and D1 are starts of table

additionaly this is the ucrrent formula im using in googlesheets

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AND((B2:D4*F2:H4)>=X, (B2:D4*F2:H4)<=Y))
```

were b2 and f2 are the beginning of each table

none of the solutions above function because it does not do what i expected.

Comment: thankyou @Tetsujin . i already tried using conditional formating but failed because excel doesnt have anyarray formula, therefor im currently trying to solve this in googlesheets. i wasnt expecting a free script or homework writing service rather asked a question which i wasnt able to solve. if i didnt get the expected solution then i will try to write a python script for it.

Comment: Thanks. First comment being removed. [It never ceases to amaze me at the small-mindedness of people who will downvote & vote to close before a new user has had chance to fix their initial mistake. If we flagged spam half as fast, life would be good.] Neither downvote nor close-vote mine btw. Wish you luck.

Comment: thank you. im used to not expecting much in the internet :). hopefully someone emerges that knows a solution to this otherwise i will write a script and post it here later

Comment: try using `=AND($A1*$D1>=($G$1-$G$2), $A1*$D1<=($G$1+$G$2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i realized this is only possible if there is a single match from table 1 to table 2

so instead i reverted the code into creating a heatmap between the two tables

code below is a python script that creates the heat map for Value of X and delta as variance where the result of multiplication should land between X-Delta and X+Delta. it saves the heatmap in two csv files called Table1_res and Table2_res in same directory. then it proceeds to draw the heatmap over the initials tables using the calculated tables

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

table1 = pd.read_csv("table1.csv",index_col=False)
table2 = pd.read_csv("table2.csv",index_col=False)
X = 600
delta = 5

num_rows, num_cols = table1.shape
table1_res = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((num_rows, num_cols)), columns=table1.columns)
num_rows, num_cols = table2.shape
table2_res= pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((num_rows, num_cols)), columns=table2.columns)

for row1 in range(table1.shape[0]):
    for col1 in range(table1.shape[1]):
        if col1 == 0:
            continue
        cell1 = table1.iloc[row1,col1]
        for row2 in range(table2.shape[0]):
            for col2 in range(table2.shape[1]):
                if col2 == 0:
                    continue
                cell2 = table2.iloc[row2,col2]
                if cell1 * cell2 >= X-delta and cell1 * cell2 <= X + delta:
                    table1_res.iloc[row1,col1] += 1
                    table2_res.iloc[row2,col2] += 1


table1_res.to_csv("table1_res.csv",index=False)
table2_res.to_csv("table2_res.csv",index=False)

#fix index
table1_res = table1_res.iloc[:,1:]
table2_res = table2_res.iloc[:,1:]
table1ylabel =table1.iloc[:,0]
table2ylabel = table2.iloc[:,0]
table1 = table1.iloc[:,1:]
table2 = table2.iloc[:,1:]

# Create a color heatmap using values from table2_subset on table1_subset
colors = ['#FFA500', '#FFFFFF']  # White to orange
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom_cmap', colors)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(12, 6))

sns.heatmap(table1_res, cmap="Reds", annot=table1, fmt=".1f", cbar=False,ax=axes[0],yticklabels=table1ylabel)
axes[0].set_title('Table 1')
axes[0].set_xlabel('Number of Emitters')
axes[0].set_ylabel('Number of Laterals')
sns.heatmap(table2_res, cmap="Reds", annot=table2, fmt=".1f", cbar=False,ax=axes[1],yticklabels=table2ylabel)
axes[1].set_title('Table 2')
axes[1].set_xlabel('Emitter Flow rate [l/h]')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Irrigation duration [h]')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[the picture is a sample of what i used this code for X = 600 and Delta = 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrHtI.png)